# How to make cygwin use the correct paths?

Tags: wordpress, command-line, cygwin

I'm trying to use [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) with cygwin. WP-CLI installed successfully, but when trying to run any of its commands in cygwin terminal, for example `wp --info`, it gives me these warnings:

```
MS-DOS style path detected: C:\cygwin\home\Evaldas\.wp-cli\vendor\wp-cli\wp-cli\php\boot-fs.php
Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /home/Evaldas/.wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php
```

and:

```
include(/home/php/wp-cli.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/Evaldas/C:\cygwin\home\Evaldas\.wp-cli\vendor\wp-cli\wp-cli\php\boot-fs.php on line 17
```

File `boot-fs.php` defines the path like so:

```
define( 'WP_CLI_ROOT', dirname( __DIR__ ) );
include WP_CLI_ROOT . '/php/wp-cli.php';
```

It is clear that the path is somewhy doubled and in a wrong format, so the question is how do i set up the paths for cygwin to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your `__DIR__` is defined in MS-DOS format, because your PHP program is installed under Windows and it is the one defining the `__DIR__` constant, not Cygwin. You can get this to work, however, by following these steps if permitted in your environment.

1. Uninstall PHP for Windows.
2. Follow the instructions on http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/ to add Cygwin ports as a source. I added one of the mirror sites, ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/sources.redhat.com/cygwinports/.
3. Run the cygstart program as they suggest and install PHP and whichever extensions you like as a Cygwin port, which is specially modified to run in the Cygwin environment.
4. Create a test program, test.php, with a line that says `echo __DIR__;` and run it from inside Cygwin. Make sure when you run test.php that it echos a path in Cygwin-style format, like /cygdrive/c/..., not Windows C:... format.